# "Template Not Found" error when trying to access a module controller action

Tags: craft3, controller, modules

I'm a total Craft newbie, so I hope this question isn't ridiculous.

I just want to see a controller / action work in my new module.

I have src/controllers/ScrapeController.php as such:

```
<?php

namespace mycompany\mymodule\controllers;

use craft\web\Controller;

class ScrapeController extends Controller {

    public function actionPush()
    {
        return $this->asJson([
            'success' => TRUE,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I just want to see this URL work: http://localhost/my-module/scrape/push

But instead I get: **HTTP 404 - Template not found**

I'm sure I'm missing something really dumb here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either need to use the action url `http://localhost/actions/my-module/scrape/push` since only those will route to controllers by default or create a custom route to your controller